# Removing a dependency in a NuGet package

Tags: nuget

I'm getting this error when updating a package:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency XRM.Client.
Circular dependency detected.
```

Is there anyway to remove the dependency? I don't know how it got there in the first place.

I have tried uninstalling and removing all references to the old package.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to having the package listed in the project's packages.config file as well as having a reference.
By leaving the reference in the project, and removing the package from the packages.config, it fixed the problem :)